# How apply redis MGET with Ruby Nest

Tags: ruby, redis

I use [nest](https://github.com/soveran/nest) in my Ruby project and it's look very convenient. But suppose I want to do multi-get request. Suppose I have set of **keys** in my Redis db with a common prefix, i.e. myapp:env:common_part:particular_part1, myapp:env:common_part:particular_part2 and so on. And I want to do MGET on it with nest. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. The [source](https://github.com/soveran/nest/blob/master/lib/nest.rb) for nest is very simple and you can see that there's no MGET method defined. Makes sense...how would MGET work in this case? :)

Comment: I see on the source code of Nest first before write this question. But I expected that someone makes a hack or find unobvious possibility of such nest usage =)